# How to get default collation in rails?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In `database.yml` i have this configuration:

```
  development:
      adapter: mysql2
      encoding: utf8
      ...
```

But `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.collation` returns `latin1_swedish_ci` this is not what i expected, because default collation is `utf8_unicode_ci`. How can i get default collation in rails?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per my knowledge you can check it on two places, remember you have also to check your mysql database. For ruby on rails you can check configuration and add as per following at end of your database.yml file

```
encoding: utf8mb4
collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Restart server and now it should be following this configuration. Than check with following command

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.collation
```

Now let us check on mysql

```
mysql> show variables like 'collation%';
```

Right now I can't check these things as mysql is not setup, so will edit later to confirm you all.

Comment: Note, I had this set in my `database.yml` and it still wouldn't create a new table (via a migration) with my desired `encoding` and `collation`. I ended up having to change the defaults on the database itself by logging into the `mysql` console and doing something like `ALTER DATABASE my_database CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`

Comment: `collation` will change when you recreate your database if it is already created then this command won't do any effect, it is just telling your connection that what type of collation.

Comment: Beauty, that makes perfect sense. It's used during the creation but not during the connection. If you need to change it after creation, you need to adjust this manually via an `ALTER` command, etc. Thanks for clarifying.